# Kotlin Gradle multiplatform for 32 bit binary

Tags: linux, kotlin-multiplatform, gradle-kotlin-dsl

I have a `build.gradle.kts` when I put `linuxX64` it is working fine
But I want 32 bit binary so I put `linuxX86` I am getting below error
I tried `linux32` `linux86` `linux` all throws error

```
plugins {
    id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.multiplatform") version "1.8.0"
}
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    mavenLocal()
    google()
}

kotlin {
    linuxX86("myplot") {
        binaries {
            executable {
                entryPoint = "test.main"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I am getting error

```
linuxX86("myplot")
   ^ Unresolved reference: linuxX86
```

Anybody knows how to force 32 bit binary ? in gradle kotlin multiplatform plugin ?

Comment: you can find list of supported platform in [documentation](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/native-target-support.html#tier-1)

Answer (score 0):

No, the 32 bit targets was deprecated, check this: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/native-target-support.html#deprecated-targets